Honda CRV Having issues starting
I have a 2015 Honda CR-V. For about a month or so, I've noticed that when I push the start button, it will sometimes go into accessory mode without starting. At first, I thought I wasn't putting my foot on the brake hard enough, but then this issue has persisted. I've always been able to get the car to start, but sometimes it takes 3-4 tries. Sometimes, it starts just fine, sometimes it goes into accessory mode, and sometime it sounds like the engine is about to start, but then it misfires and I have to try again. It seems to be a bigger issue in hotter weather, but I haven't conclusively tested that.
After looking online for some solutions, I saw one potential fix was to replace the air filter. The filter was pretty dirty, so I got a new one, but it didn't fix the problem. My battery is about 6 months old, and I took it to get looked at. I went to Firestone auto to check the battery, the starter, and the alternator. They told me the starter and the alternator were working perfectly, and the voltage on the battery was good, but the cold cranking amps were at 378, when they should be at around 450. I then went to Advance Auto Parts (where I have a warranty on the battery) to ask if they would replace the battery, but then they ran their own test and told me the battery (both voltage and cold cranking amps), starter, and alternator were all fine.
It seems this may be an internal electrical issue. I was on the phone with a mechanic, but he seemed confused about the problem, so I'm hesitant to pay him to look at it. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Has the vehicle had spark plugs and fuel filter replaced?
If the vehicle idles "hard" or has lost some fuel efficiency, you may have a vacuum leak also.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
